# Can't recover my account, and can't set up a new one with the same email address

Tags: support, jobs, login

This all happened on the careers site...

I can't remember which openid I used to log in. When I tried to retrieve it I got this email:

Someone requested a Stack Overflow Careers account recovery for this email address. If this was not you, please disregard this email.

You have the following credentials associated with your Stack Overflow Careers account:

None
No OpenId yet. This is a passive candidate.517b9b07-fc65-42e2-8397-16ad6d182382

I tried using forgot password linkage and ended up at a 404.

Any ideas how to retrieve my account?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about that... Can you try again? (you used facebook to login.) There was an issue with your account but that should be fixed now.